# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace'). I am facing this error in my site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, replace, typeerror, undefined

I am using this code on the WordPress website and errors continuously coming to my site.

```
<script>
            function setNiceResult(valor, id){
                var div = $("#"+id);
                valor = valor.replace(/\{\{/g, "<strong class=\"fuerte\">").replace("}}", "</strong>");
                valor = valor.replace(/\}\}/g, "</strong>");
                valor = valor.replace(/\{/g, "<strong class=\"medio\">").replace("}", "</strong>");
                valor = valor.replace(/\}/g, "</strong>");
                div.html(valor);
                window.redrawMasonry(); // NO BORRAR!
            }
        </script>
```

[This picture shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Oxd.png)

Comment: valor = valor?.replace(/\{\{/g, "<strong class=\"fuerte\">")?.replace("}}", "</strong>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are receiving this error is because the variable valor does not have a value assigned to it and thus is `undefined`.

`replace()` is a function that acts on `string` values.

PROBLEM:

```js
var sentence; // value is undefined
sentence = sentence.replace("word", "new word");  // trying to execute replace function in undefined type
console.log("sentence: ", sentence);
```

**Solution 1:**
To prevent the error from occuring, you can assign an empty string value.

```js
   var sentence = ''; // value is undefined
sentence = sentence.replace("word", "new word");  // trying to execute replace function in undefined type
console.log("sentence: ", sentence);
```

**Solution 2:**

You can use a `?` optional chaining operator to only execute replace function if the value is not `undefined`:

```js
var sentence;
sentence = sentence?.replace("word", "new word");
console.log("sentence: ", sentence);



var anotherSentence = "Some word value";
anotherSentence = anotherSentence?.replace("word", "new word");
console.log("anotherSentence: ", anotherSentence);
```